# I'm trying to code a tic tac toe-game in python but running on a problem when I'm trying to do the 'move'

Tags: python, nested-lists

When I'm trying to do the move or more specifically change the element in the nested list, depending on what move to do, I'm instead changing the last element in all of the nested lists. I think I've constructed the list with the nested list correctly and that the problem lies in my method show_board. However I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
class TicTacToe:

    def __init__(self, sz):
        self.sz = sz
        self.board = []
    
    def create_board(self):
        """Creating the game board with the given size."""
        self.column = []

        for _ in range(self.sz):
            self.column.append('-')
            self.board.append(self.column)
        return self.board
        
    
    def check_board(self):
        """Checking if the board is full."""
        for row in self.board:
            for spot in row:
                if spot == '-':
                    return False
                
        return True
    
    def check_win(self, player):
        """Method for checking if a player has won the game. Evaluating rows, columns and 
        diagonals."""
        win = None
        

        #Checking rows for win:
        for row in range(len(self.board)):
            # win = True
            for column in range(len(self.column)):
                if self.board[row][column] == player:
                    continue
                else:
                    win = False
                    return win
            win = True
            return win
                
        

        #Checking columns for win:
        for column in range(len(self.column)):
            for row in range(len(self.board)):
                if self.board[column][row] == player:
                    continue
                else:
                    win = False
                    return win
            win = True
            return win
        
        #Checking first diagonal for win:
        for spot in range(len(self.board)):
            if self.board[spot][spot] == player:
                continue
            elif self.board[spot][spot] == '-':
                win = False
                return win
            win = True
            return win
        #Checking second diagonal for win:
        for spot in range(len(self.board)):
            if self.board[len(self.board)-spot-1][len(self.board)-spot-1] == player:
                continue
            elif self.board[len(self.board)-spot-1][len(self.board)-spot-1] == player:
                win = False
                return win
            win = True 
            return win
    
    def show_board(self):
        """Showing the current board"""
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end=" ")
            print()
    
    def get_random_first_player(self):
        """Randomizing the first player."""
        if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            player = 'X'
        else:
            player = 'O'
        return player 
    
    def players_turn(self, player):
        """Changing the players turn."""
        return 'X' if player == 'O' else 'O'
    
    def place_move(self, row, column, player):
        """Placing the move, namely putting the players
        symbol in the list at the given place."""
        self.board[row][column] = player
       
      


    def start(self):
        
        self.create_board()
        player = self.get_random_first_player()
        while True:
            print(f'It is {player} turn')
            self.show_board()
            row = int(input('Enter row: '))
            column = int(input('Enter column: '))
            print()
            # row, column = list(
            #     map(int, input("Enter row and column numbers to fix spot: ").split()))
            # print()
            self.place_move(row - 1, column - 1, player)
            if self.check_win(player):
                print(f'{player} wins the game')
                break
            if self.check_board():
                print('We have a draw')
                break
            player = self.players_turn(player)
        print()
        self.show_board()

v = TicTacToe(3)
v.start()
```

Comment: Your board has only one column that is repeated several times.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
self.column = []

for _ in range(self.sz):
    self.column.append('-')
    self.board.append(self.column)
```

Each column in the board is actually a reference to `self.column`. Therefore, when one of the members of any of the columns changes, that member changes in all columns.

To get around this, use

```
self.board.append(self.column.copy())
```

Now, each column of your board is a separate object.